# Написать программу для ввода ФИО студентов группы и сортировки этого списка по алфавиту

Tags: c++, сортировка

Известно, что в группе n человек. Написать программу для ввода ФИО студентов группы и сортировки этого списка по алфавиту.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "ru");
    vector<string> students;
    string FIO;
    int n, j = 0, p = 0;
    cout << "Введите количество студентов в группе: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;


    for (int i = 0; i != n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите ФИО " << ++j << "го студента: ";
        getline(cin, FIO);
        students.push_back(FIO);
    }

    cout << "\nОтсортированный по алфавиту список студентов:" << endl;
    sort(students.begin(), students.end());
    for (vector<string>::iterator it = students.begin(); it != students.end(); ++it)
        cout << ++p << ". " << *it << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в переводе строки при вводе количества студентов, считалось только число, а символ `\n`, нет. Для очистки, перед циклом, можно использовать либо такое правильное решение:

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Либо такое, понятное:

```
getline(cin, FIO);
```

P.S. Правильное и понятное - в данном контексте субъективно.